# Customising Drupal User Profiles

Tags: php, jquery, css, drupal

i'm trying to customise the user profiles in my Drupal website and need your help with two things.

The first is the 'View | Edit | Manage Display' tabs menu. Is there a way I can add a class to the parent div? The structure is usually:

```
<div data-thmr="thmr_22">
    <div class="tabs">
        <h2 class="element-invisible" data-thmr="thmr_39">Primary tabs</h2>
```

I've tried adding a class using jQuery parent selector but to no avail.

My second question is regarding the default profile page a user is presented with (below). It displays their history, orders, emails, etc but I was wondering if I was able to customise the content it displays and add a view or custom blocks to it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "customise the content it displays" you mean take some of those tabs off, yes very simply with a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module. This page may be helpful if you chose this route: https://drupal.org/node/483324

However, you may be better to customise the whole profile with the default panel pages for user edit and user display. Googling will get you lots of tutorials for that.